# Stop sharing pictures to another device

Tags: iphone, ios, photos

I share an iCloud with my aunt and I turned off my iCloud Photo Sharing and Photo Stream. However, my aunt still is able to automatically get my pictures on her device. How do I stop that from happening?

Answer (score 2):

She still has access to the account.

If you and your aunt are using the same account then she can still have access. You should make sure that she has her own account so that you can send her a shared album of photos instead of the entire gallery.

Comment: Could also be Family Sharing

Comment: Yep or shared photo album.